# How to get an imported image transparent with PHP GD?

Tags: php, image, transparency, gd

I created a PNG image (createimagefrompng()) but the transparency won't work.

### How to get this work?

Edit:
My script:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$bg = imagecreatefrompng('banner_bg.png'); // Background Image
$image = imagecreatefrompng('http://<link>/image.png');
$wit = imagecolorallocatealpha($bg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagecolortransparent($bg, $wit);
imagealphablending($obe, false);

imagecopy($image, $bg, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);

imagegif($bg);

imagedestroy($bg);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

*------
Sorry for my bad English.*

Comment: Don't apologise for your English - it's fine. Apologise for the lack of information in your question. We need to know _much_ more about your problem.

Comment: I hope i did add enough information for you.

Answer (score 1):

After calling createimagefrompng() you need to call:

```
imagealphablending($img, true); // setting alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($img, true); // save alphablending setting (important)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the transparent color using [`imagecolortransparent()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php). Also, you will need to use [`imagealphablending()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) to set the alpha blender.